# Why am I receiving the "TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer" error:

Tags: python-3.x, websocket

I have two pieces of code. One which I consider rather messy, and the former is my attempt to clean it up.
The first piece of code looks like this:

```
# create the if loop for option 2, port listener.
if choice=='2':
# take the target host ip as user input and store it in a variable
    host = input('Please enter target host: ')
# take the target port and store it in a variable
    port = int(input('Please enter target port'))
# check the connection for errors
    try:
        s.bind((host, port))
# if the connection fails, display an error message.
    except socket.error as e:
        print(str(e))
# listen for the connection with the maximum number of queued connections being five.
    s.listen(5)
# accept the connection from client
    conn, addr = s.accept()
# display a message on the client machine.
    print('pwned: '+addr[0]+':'+str(addr[1]))
```

This runs fine.

In my attempt to convert this into a function, however, I'm met with the TypeError bug which is baffling me, though I am learning.
Here is the 2nd piece of code:

```
def listen():
    host = input("Please enter your target host IP: ")
    port = input("Please enter target port: ")
    try:
        s.bind((host, port))
    except socket.error as e:
        print(str(e))
    s.listen(5)
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    print("pwned: "+addr[0]+":"+str(addr[1]))


listen()
```

Any and all help is appreciated. I apologize for any annoying questions, or migraine inducing code.

So far I've tried changing `print(str(e))` to `print(int(e))` which yields the same error.

Comment: You're missing the conversion of `port` to an `int`.

Comment: It was one of those... Thank you for being so accomodating and understanding, I need to practice reading over my stuff more often.

Comment: Also, `print` converts its arguments to `str`, so if you aren't using `+` for concatenation, just outputting raw arguments with `print`, plain `print(e)` will do the trick. In more complex cases like your final `print`, f-strings are the way to go `print(f"pwned: {addr[0]}:{addr[1]}")`; no type conversion is typically required, and it builds a single output string efficiently rather than producing multiple temporary strings from repeated concatenation.

Comment: That looks much cleaner! Thank you!